# Is there a way to output a string from one excel cell to another?

Tags: excel

I want to output a string from one cell into another cell. The string will always start with #0, and then there will be 4 to 7 characters following it. For example, for this cell:

```
UI-ESR25893-TA-03-0022 STEAMPLANT-#0009-R1 - Utility Tie-In Drawings-handled out of DRS - close
```

I'd want to output "0009-R1" to the new cell.

Comment: You can do this using a regex in VBA. This answer should help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using below formula where the example text resides in cell A1

`=MID(A1,FIND("#0",A1,1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND("#0",A1,1))-FIND("#0",A1,1)-1)`

where,

`FIND("#0",A1,1)` locates position where #0 exists and then we add 1 to it to get rid of #.

`FIND(" ",A1,FIND("#0",A1,1))` locates the first space after #0 occurs

`FIND(" ",A1,FIND("#0",A1,1))-FIND("#0",A1,1)-1` works out the exact length of the string.